# Taking only characters from the left and right of a specific character in mySQL

Tags: mysql, string, locate

I have a list table with where one of the variables is Player and if has a players first name then an "_" and there last name like this:

```
Mike_Gonzalez
```

I would like to create two new variables from the player variables. The first variable would be firstName, so I would want all the characters to the left of the "*". The second variable would be lastName, and it would be all the characters to the right of the "*".

I've tried using LEFT(Player, LOCATE('_', Player)), but when I do, the new variable includes the _ .

How can I run the code where I would be able to jus get the first and last names without the _  ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides combining `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` with `LOCATE()`, you can also use **[`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)**:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Player, '_', 1) AS FirstName
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX(Player, '_', -1) AS LastName
```

Answer (score 3):

```
LEFT(Player, (LOCATE('_', Player) - 1))
```

You just basicly decrease the value of the second parameter in `LEFT` by 1 to exclude the `_`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct left(HOST,locate (':',HOST)-1) CONNECTED_HOST 
from information_schema.processlist 
where User != 'root' 
order by 1;
```