# SQL Query Find & Trim

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a URL (example: https://mycompoany.com/data/test) and want to remove everything left of test.  What is the best way to do this?

I was going to use like the following.  However, I'm not sure how to return the length of the last /.

```
LEN(LTRIM(THE_TEXT))
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7856777/1313067 .

Comment: Side note: `LEN` is a SQL Server function. In MySQL you need to use the `LENGTH` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` with -1 for the counter argument like this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(THE_TEXT, '/', -1)
```

For example, this line:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('https://mycompoany.com/data/test', '/', -1)
```

returns `test`.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone for the assistance.  It is greatly appreciated.  Here is what I ended up doing.

```
SELECT top 10 profile_url,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('/', profile_url) > 0 THEN
            RIGHT(profile_url, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(profile_url))-1)
        ELSE profile_url
    END
FROM connections
```

Comment: So why did you tag it with MySQL?